# swift UIView animateWithDuration with repeat and autoreverse

Tags: ios, swift, animation, animatewithduration

I am new to swift and this is my first question ever ....
I would like to shrink a ball with duration 2 seconds, and then grow it for a duration of 5 seconds.
My problem is that the second duration is ignored (ball shrinks for 2 seconds and grows for 2 seconds). 
I hope someone can help me.

This is my attempt:

```
    let ball = UIView()
    ball.frame = CGRectMake(50, 50, 50, 50)
    ball.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    ball.layer.cornerRadius=25
    relaxContainer.addSubview(ball)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(2.0, delay:0, options: [.Repeat, .Autoreverse], animations: {
        ball.frame = CGRectMake(50, 50, 20, 20)
        }, completion: { finished in
            UIView.animateWithDuration(5.0, animations: {
                ball.frame = CGRectMake(50, 50, 50, 50)
            })
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

My Answer thanks to help by Matt (duration times, variables from original question were changed):

**Swift 2**

```
let duration = 6.0
let delay = 0.0
UIView.animateKeyframesWithDuration(duration, delay: delay, options: [.Repeat], animations: {
    UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(0, relativeDuration: 1/3, animations: {
        ball.frame = CGRectMake(screenWidth/8*3, screenHeight/8*3, screenWidth/4, screenWidth/4)
    })
    UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(1/3, relativeDuration: 2/3, animations: {
        ball.frame = CGRectMake(screenWidth/4, screenHeight/4, screenWidth/2, screenWidth/2)
    })
    }, completion: nil
)
```

**Swift 3, 4, 5**

```
let duration = 6.0
let delay = 0.0
UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: duration, delay: delay, options: [.repeat], animations: {
    UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0, relativeDuration: 1/3, animations: {
        ball.frame = CGRect(x: screenWidth/8*3, y: screenHeight/8*3, width: screenWidth/4, height: screenWidth/4)
    })
    UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 1/3, relativeDuration: 2/3, animations: {
        ball.frame = CGRect(x: screenWidth/4, y: screenHeight/4, width: screenWidth/2, height: screenWidth/2)
    })
    }, completion: nil
)
```

Comment: Remember to nil out your completion block if you're not using it, to keep your code clean :)