# UIView.animate with repeat option stops when new View Controller is presented

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview, uiviewanimation

I have a View Controller with one animation that is set to loop indefinitely with `options: [.autoreverse, .repeat]` - This works perfect, however, when I present a new View Controller (the Settings VC) - then dismiss it to return to the view with the animation, the animation is not animating. The view (`ballContainer`) just remains static, when it SHOULD still be animating.

**animateBallViewIn method**

```
func animateBallViewIn() {
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
        self.ballContainer.alpha = 1.0
    }) { (true) in

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, options: [.autoreverse, .repeat], animations: {
            ballViewBottomConstraint = 20.0

            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Note - I'm calling `animateBallViewIn()` in a property observer.

**How can I keep the above animation animating after returning to it from presenting another View Controller?**

Comment: Call this function inside of viewWillAppear!

Comment: @Mannopson - issue persists in viewDidAppear / viewWillAppear

Answer (score 1):

The animation will stop if the view disappears or app is minimised/maximised. This is expected behaviour.

To solve this, you should evaluate the need for animation in `viewDidAppear` and `applicationDidBecomeActive` and call your `animateBallViewIn` method if necessary.

Comment: I'm now checking the need for animation, and calling animateBallViewIn accordingly within 'viewDidAppear' - The issue still persists. When I come back to the view after tapping the Settings screen, the animation does not animate :(

Answer (score 0):

you could remove all animations from the view and then restart the animation using the [.beginFromCurrentState] option.

Answer (score 0):

**Way to work around the error**:
Set up a timer where every .3(example time) your animation will go off, with a completion to 'autoreverse' it. Do not include the repeat part in here, because whenever the timer sets off the action every .3 seconds the animation will repeat automatically.

If you still need help, this may help you out:

[swift UIView animateWithDuration with repeat and autoreverse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34709916/swift-uiview-animatewithduration-with-repeat-and-autoreverse)

Answer (score 0):

When doing a repeat constraint animation, in addition to triggering the animation in viewWillAppear, you have to set the constraint back to its starting position in viewWillDisappear.  in my case it looked like this

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.myConstraint.constant = 0
}
```

because I had

```
self.myConstraint.constant = 20
```

in my animation block.